# jsonb_path_query with order by child

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a nested json structure

```
{
  "feed": {
    "3": {
       "id1": {
          "id": "activity-1",
          "created": 1469905513973,
          "verb": "added recipe 1"
       },
       "id2": {
          "id": "activity-2",
          "created": 1470013085119,
          "verb": "added recipe 2"
       },
       "id3": {
          "id": "activity-3",
          "created": 1472341861543,
          "verb": "added recipe 3"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to select everything in `/feed/3` and order by `created`.

I have been unable to figure out the correct syntax.

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query(
    '{ "feed": { "3": { "id1": { "id": "activity-1", "created": 1469905513973, "verb": "added recipe 1" }, "id2": { "id": "activity-2", "created": 1470013085119, "verb": "added recipe 2" }, "id3": { "id": "activity-3", "created": 1472341861543, "verb": "added recipe 3" } } } }',
     '$."feed"."3".*')
 order by "created" desc;
```

this version gives me an `ERROR:  column "created" does not exist`

with no order by clause, the output looks like

```
# SELECT jsonb_path_query('{ "feed": { "3": { "id1": { "id": "activity-1", "created": 1469905513973, "verb": "added recipe 1" }, "id2": { "id": "activity-2", "created": 1470013085119, "verb": "added recipe 2" }, "id3": { "id": "activity-3", "created": 1472341861543, "verb": "added recipe 3" } } } }', '$."feed"."3".*');
                             jsonb_path_query                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": "activity-1", "verb": "added recipe 1", "created": 1469905513973}
 {"id": "activity-2", "verb": "added recipe 2", "created": 1470013085119}
 {"id": "activity-3", "verb": "added recipe 3", "created": 1472341861543}
(3 rows)
```

I'm pretty certain it is some side-effect of jsonb_path_query returning a set, but I don't know how to handle it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result doesn't contain a column named `created`, only a column named `jsonb_path_query` that contains the JSON value.

You need to extract the number from the JSON in order to be able to sort it. It's also recommended to use set returning functions in the FROM clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM jsonb_path_query('{...}', '$."feed"."3".*') as t(item)
order by (item ->> 'created')::bigint desc;
```